# Tooltiped agregado con js

Tags: javascript, webservice, materialize

Que tal estoy creando botones con js y el estilo se lo doy con materialze, la logica del codigo es poder consumir el servicio web y dependiendo de lo que responda crear un boton con un tooltip, pero cuando mando el codigo para la creacion este no toma las propiedades y no muestra el tooltip, lo contrario de un boton creado con codigo normal que si me funciona mi pregunta es si estoy haciendo algo mal si mem pueden ayudar porfavor

```
<script>   
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        name(response.tipo);
    });
</script>


<script>
    function name(cont) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>';
    }
</script>



<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped');
        var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Creo que faltan elementos de tu código que nos pueden ayudar a darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

la solucion fue la siguiente colocar el evento con jquery no js dentro de esta clase

```html
<script>
  function name(cont, entidad) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<img src="bullet-red.png" class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="' + entidad + '">';

      $('.tooltipped').tooltip();

    })

  }
</script>
```